# how to pull an element to my cursor?

Tags: jquery, html, css

There is a blue square and it has a picture of a boat with figures. I would like to travel with the mouse pointer within the blue square and the picture with the boat closer to the mouse cursor.
how to pull an element to my cursor and is there solution in css3?
Many Thx.
   [Demo](http://www.centerwow.com/stackoverflow/Games_ship.html)

Comment: If possible you should include the relevant code, images, etc. of what you currently tried or have a question about in addition to an external link. This way if another person someday has a similar question they can see the data you posted even if the link is dead. If the posted link is dead at some stage the question could make little to no sense in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="square">[]</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#wrapper{width:400px; height:500px; background:#eeeeee; cursor:pointer;}
#square{font-size:36px; font-weight:bold; position:absolute;}
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#wrapper').on('mousemove', function(e){
     $('#square').offset({
       top: parseInt(e.pageY - $('#square').height() / 2),
       left: parseInt(e.pageX - $('#square').width() / 2)
     });
  }); 
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qXKZh/)**

Comment: i think this isn´t what he means, i think he means that the boat is slowly coming at his mouse, like it´s floating on the blue water.

Comment: @KeesSonnema If so, take a look at this **[NEW DEMO!](http://jsfiddle.net/qXKZh/4/)**

Comment: I think it's something like that :)

Comment: this isn't my problem, i only pointed you to the real problem but thanks :)

Comment: @KeesSonnema Yes, I know it. Thank you for your comments :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly - you wish to move the picture closer to the user's mouse position whilst it's inside the blue square?

This definitely seems like something that you're going to need Javascript / JQuery for - CSS won't be able to do it dynamically.

I would look into [this JQuery tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aMouse_Position) to find the user's mouse position within the `<div>` and from there move your image (again with JQuery) towards that position.